# numpy reshape tensor into matrix

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, tensor

I would like to know if the following is correct.

I would like to do the dyadic product between two identity tensors.

```
import numpy as np
a  = np.tensordot(np.eye(3),np.eye(3),axes=0)
```

The output is:

```
array([[[[1., 0., 0.],
     [0., 1., 0.],
     [0., 0., 1.]],

    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]]],


   [[[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[1., 0., 0.],
     [0., 1., 0.],
     [0., 0., 1.]],

    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]]],


   [[[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[1., 0., 0.],
     [0., 1., 0.],
     [0., 0., 1.]]]])
```

Which I assume is calculated as: https://ibb.co/5nvG2Nm

I would like to "flatten" the tensor into a matrix:

If I do:

```
np.tensordot(np.eye(3),np.eye(3),axes=0).reshape(9,9)

array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

But I was hopping do get:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

If my understanding of the tensor structure wrong? Or is the reshape function not reshaping correctly?

Comment: [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) defaults to C contiguous ordering, you can use `np.tensordot(np.eye(3),np.eye(3),axes=0).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(9,9)`, but `np.eye(9)` works as well.

Comment: Your desired array is ambiguous. Please try whether `np.einsum('ij,kl->ikjl', np.arange(3*3).reshape(3,3), np.eye(3)).reshape(9,9)` or `np.einsum('ij,kl->jkil', np.arange(3*3).reshape(3,3), np.eye(3)).reshape(9,9)` is correct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But having to swap the axis either by `swapaxes` or `einsum` to me seems quirky. But has long as the operations being made in the image are true, I can swap the axis :)

Comment: The only package supporting *block-wise reshape* I know of is [einops](https://github.com/arogozhnikov/einops). A solution would look like `einops.rearrange(a, 'r c m0 m1 -> (c m0) (r m1)')`.